# Search entire workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with many hidden sheets, and I want to search all the sheets for a particular string. I don't want to unhide all of the sheets and use the Excel search feature because it's difficult to keep track of which sheets should be hidden and which should not. I wrote the following code to try to search all the sheets using VBA:

```
Sub SearchWorkbook()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

For I = 1 To WS_Count
        
    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
    
    With WS
        Set r = .Cells.Find(What:="string I want to find", After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Found at " & WS.Name & " " & r.address
    End If

Next I

End Sub
```

When I run this I get at most one search result per worksheet, but I know for a fact there's a worksheet where the string occurs 3 times. How do I return all matches for the string, and not just the first one on each worksheet?

Comment: Take a look at the `Range.FindNext` method. This can be used to find multiple matches in a sheet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext

Comment: Also  worth  using `For Each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets...Next WS` rather than counting the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

find function of Excel always selects only 1 result, always the first one. 
If you want to find multiple cells matching your criteria, you need to put a phrase
`Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate` 
into a loop - it will select/indicate next finding.

I'd:

- put this code into while loop
- store row and column index for each finding in dictionary and validate each found row/column at the beginning of the loop
- leave the loop if specific row/column was already "found"
- go to next sheet